# 404 error page after refreshing dynamic route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, custom-error-pages

I am using 2.15.8 version of Nuxt. When I refresh the page like: `localhost:3000/products/(product.id)` browser returning 404 page

`product.id` comes from database(firebase).

I have tried `npm generate` but it could not help for my issue and I tried to use `dynamic-routes.js` file like plugin which consist in:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    generate: {
        routes() {
            return axios
                .get(
                    'https://my-api/products.json'
                )
                .then((res) => {
                    const data = Object.keys(res.data)
                    return data.map((value) => {
                        return '/products/' + res.data[value].urlsId
                    })
                })
        }
    }
}
```

And it also could not help.

Could you share with your advices related to this isuue please?

Comment: What is the (product.id) ? may be not present in the database.

Comment: No, there is an id in database, like uuid

Answer (score 0):

at first check if api is working properly on postman, then move to coding part.

Also you can save fetched data into a variable and then use that variable to retrieve data. So you don't need to hit api continuously if its not dynamic.

Comment: You mean save to localStorage? Because if browser refreshs all my variables will be equal to null

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOD7z.png

See the data variable in data-return, Save the fetched results from api in that variable

For example if you fetched data in results, then next line of code would be -
this.data = results